# Loaded page in div doesn't work for submit form

Tags: php, jquery, loading

I got an index.php with a menu which loads pages using jQuery

```
<div id="cont">
<div class="menu">
    <ul>
    <li>COMPRAS
        <ul>
        <li><p id="link1">Registrar</p></li>
        <li><p id="link11">Reporte Mensual</p></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="resu"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#link1").click(function(event) {
                $(".resu").load('sys_compra/compra_agregar.php');
            });
            $("#link11").click(function(event) {
                $(".resu").load('sys_compra/compra_reportem_sol.php');
            });
        });
</script>
```

The php file works perfectly when i run it alone but when i load it through index.php it doesn't work.
this is the compra_agregar.php code

```
<fieldset>
<legend>GENERAR REPORTE DE COMPRAS MENSUAL</legend>
<p>SELECCIONE EL MES Y EL AÑO QUE DESEA</p>
<table>
<form name="impres1" action="compra_reportem_mes.php" method="post" onsubmit="presupuesto1()">
<tr>
<td align="center">MES</td>
<td align="center">AÑO</td>
<td align="center">ESTADO</td>
<td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<select name="id">
<option value="01">ENERO</option>
<option value="02">FEBRERO</option>
<option value="03">MARZO</option>
<option value="04">ABRIL</option>
<option value="05">MAYO</option>
<option value="06">JUNIO</option>
<option value="07">JULIO</option>
<option value="08">AGOSTO</option>
<option value="09">SEPTIEMBRE</option>
<option value="10">OCTUBRE</option>
<option value="11">NOVIEMBRE</option>
<option value="12">DICIEMBRE</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input name="idy" required placeholder="Ingrese Año"/>
</td>
<td>
<select name="est">
<option value="0">REGISTRADO</option>
<option value="1">OPERADO</option>
<option value="2">ANULADO</option>
<option value="3">RECIBIDO</option>
</select>
</td>
<td>
<input type="submit" value="IMPRIMIR REPORTE">
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
</fieldset>
```

script which doesn't work when i load it using jQuery

```
<script>
function presupuesto1() {
var mds = "width="+screen.width+"px,height="+(screen.height - 50) + "px,top=0,left=0";
window.open('', 'formpopup', mds);
impres1.target = 'formpopup';
};
</script>
```

Comment: Which kinf of error do you see in the javascript console...press F12 on Chrome, then go to the console Tab and see what happens when you press the `link1` button....saludos desde Chile :)

Comment: los archivos php individuales en sí no tienen errores, lo que pasa es que cuando los cargo por medio de jQuery al DIV ya no funcionan los scripts ni el action del formulario, pero respondiendo a tu petición, no me aparece ningun error cuando presiono LINK1 en la consola.

Comment: `presupuesto1()` la defines en el archivo compra_agregar.php o en el index.php??

Comment: La defino en compra_agregar.php, index.php solamente se encarga de mostrarlo a traves de jQuery

Comment: Lo suponía....he ahi el error....prueba definiendo esa función en el index.php....es ahi donde tiene que existir

Comment: si el problema es que no pretendo cargar solamente compra_agregar.php sino varías mas, por lo que eso no serviría de mucho, no sabes si usando .live o .on se pueda resolver el asunto? Gracias por tu atención y saludos desde Guatemala ;)

Comment: Si te fijas..cuando cargas un documento, sus funciones y todo se crean durante el document.ready o en el load, y con jquery alteras parte del dom solamente, pero dentro de lo ya definido...por ende, `presupuesto1` no existe en el contexto actual del documento....yo juntaria todas esas funciones que tienes en tus php y las dejaría en un unico archivo javascript, el cual incluiria en el index.php...saludos y suerte :)

Comment: mmm... eso parece tener mayor sentido, aunque hubiese sido mejor si se podía dejar como estaba XD pero ni modo. Gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: probé como me dijiste pero no funcionó

Comment: creo que seguiré con los iframes esos no fallaban jajaja....